# Google Spreadsheets API Query orderby multiple columns

Tags: c#, java, google-sheets-api

I am querying my Google Spreadsheets through the API ([here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) is the functionality).

They offer the `orderby` functionality to query a worksheet in a specific order and not only by the `row number`, for example:

```
<worksheet_feed_url>?orderby=column:lastname
```

And this will give you that worksheet ordered by the column lastname (*field names got from the first row of the worksheet*).

So I want to query this, but for multiple columns, for example if I would want to order by not only `lastname`, but also `firstname` and etc.

I have already tried with:

- `orderby=column:lastname,firstname`
- `orderby=column:lastname,column:firstname`
- `orderby=column:lastname&orderby=column:firstname`

And they don't work. If it isn't possible I would also want to know. Thank you.

Comment: @Nick Sorry I didn't understand, I am trying to order with multiple query, so the `orderby` parameter should contain more than one column or maybe another way where the query URL specifies more than one column.